# Disable FTP commands on a per-user basis

Tags: configuration, ftp, vsftpd, command, deny

I'm in the process of configuring an FTP server, using vsftp. I wish to have a couple different users. Some of these should only be able to read files, others should only be able to put files and some of these should also be able to create directories.

I am investigating whether it is possible to use `cmds_allowed` or `cmds_denied` on a per-user basis, so that, for example, certain users will fail to execute `PUT` or `MKD` while other users will succeed.

However it seems like these are only per-server options and, thus, not configurable on a per-user basis. Is this correct?
There is no way to use them with different users?

Comment: Have you tried file permissions to achieve this?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I'm looking for security in depth, so I'm asking whether it is feasible to *also* add the "commands filters" on a per user basis in addition to whichever permission I give to the user on the file system.